# PHP regular expression space or newline before or after

Tags: php, regex, newline, space

I need to detect locations of start and end in several lines of pseudo code.

Basically, if the word "start" or the word "end" has a space or newline before and after, I need to record the match.

The space/newline recognition is important since start or end could be part of the contents that appears between start and end, i.e.

```
start
 start_time = 2
  end_time = 5
end
```

So far tried

```
preg_match('/((\s)|( *)(start)(\s)|( *))|((\s)|( *)(end)(\s)|( *))/i',
$line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

...and variations.

Comment: what is the input and expected output

Comment: PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE allows me to get the position of the match, so in a large file with many start and end blocks I could get the locations without having to store the block... input a file, output array(start,0)array(end,32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture this block:

```
(?<= |\A)start(?=\s)[\s\S]*(?<=\s)end(?=\s|\z)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vW2jF2/2)

Comment: that works great for capturing the block. it's a solution if I don't find a way of capturing the indexes

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by `way of capturing the indexes`.

Comment: loading a file into a string and then capturing the index position of the s character of start and the e character of end, i.e. the beginning of each word. That way I can jump to that location without having to parse the contents completely. thanks

Comment: Alright then `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` would be helpful for you as you commented earlier.